# Get http status code of request in Vue and Ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, http, vue.js

I would like to get the HTTP status code when a form has been sent(the function for sending the form...):

```
return fetch(serviceUrl + 'Collect', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + DataLayer.instance.token
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify(
        (mergedFormObjects),{
        "UserId": this.oidcIdToken 
    }),
  });
}
```

base on that status code (201 for success; else - "user must correct data) I would like to show notifications(which I am going to/and ready/ use vue-notification framework)):

```
if (statusCode = 201) {
 *the code which show the notification for success* } 
else { *the code which show the notification for correct errors* }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the then() function you can handle the response of your call. Accessing the status code is extremely simple. I added a simple snippet which you should be able to adapt for your needs.

```js
return fetch(serviceUrl + 'Collect', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + DataLayer.instance.token
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify(
        (mergedFormObjects),{
            "UserId": this.oidcIdToken
        }),
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.status);
});
```